# std::regex_search() isn't accepting my arguments

Tags: c++, visual-c++, visual-studio-2012, c++11

I'm trying to compile the following code in Visual Studio Ultimate 2012. It's giving me an error saying that I'm calling an overload that doesn't exist for the template regex_search().

```
#include <regex>

struct Token
{
    //lexertl token wrapper...
};

class Lexer
{
    //...
    Token &curr;
    bool skipUntil(const std::regex &regexp);
};

bool Lexer::skipUntil(const std::regex &regexp)
{
    std::smatch m;
    const char *str = curr.results.start._Ptr; //compiles
    //ERROR ON NEXT LINE (overload doesn't exist, but it should...)
    if(std::regex_search(str, regexp, m)) {
        curr.results.start = m[0].first;
        curr.results.end = curr.results.start;
    }
}
```

This is the template I'm trying to use, which as far as I can tell exists...

```
//from <regex>
template <class charT, class Alloc, class traits>
  bool regex_search (const charT* s, match_results<const charT*, Alloc>& m,
  const basic_regex<charT,traits>& rgx,
  regex_constants::match_flag_type flags = regex_constants::match_default);
```

I know an easy fix would be to just convert the const char * to a std::string, but that's too expensive of an operation to consider.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The arguments to [`regex_search`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/regex/regex_search) are being passed in the wrong order. The second argument should be `std::match_results`, and the third `std::basic_regex`.

Also, `std::smatch`, or `std::match_results<std::string::const_iterator>` is used when the first argument to `regex_search` is `std::string`. Since you're passing in a `char const *`, you must use `std::cmatch` (or `std::match_results<const char*>`). The following code compiles.

```
char const *str = "";
std::cmatch m;
std::regex regexp;
std::regex_search(str, m, regexp);
```

---

```
const char *str = curr.results.start._Ptr;
```

The line above looks very suspicious. If `curr.results.start` is some type from the C++ standard library, you definitely shouldn't be accessing that `_Ptr` member, it's supposed to be an implementation detail. Using it will make your code non-portable; it might even break when you upgrade to VS2013.

Comment: The _Ptr is a bit iffy. I'm unsure if it's an internal representation specific to Visual Studio or just a lexertl thing. I believe all iterators have _Ptr in VS.

Comment: @ffhighwind If that's an iterator, then it's definitely an implementation detail. Anything from the standard library with a leading underscore followed by an uppercase letter is not meant for public use. You should be able to get access to underlying pointer by using `&(*curr.results.start)`

Comment: I ended up using the iterator version of regex_search(curr.results.start, curr.results.eoi, ...) to get around pointer/iterator conversion. I'm probably scrapping the whole project sadly and going to use ANTLR since it will be more maintainable. I was hesitant but they're working on a C++ version for v4 that I can migrate to later.